# JSON syntax - variable being interpreted as a literal

Tags: javascript, json

I run the following code in a JS function. The argument `value` contains a user-id string:

```
function create_acl(value) {
    var acl = { value : { "read": true, "write": true}};
    return acl;
}
```

If value = "123" then I'm expecting the result to be:

```
{ "123": {"read": true, "write": true}}
```

However, what I'm getting is:

```
{"value":{"read":true,"write":true}}
```

As you can see, the code is interpreting `value` as a literal. Does anyone know how to rewrite this to get the required behaviour?

The original question (above) was expanded after some discussion:

I need to create an acl with 2 entries in it, one for a particulat user-id and one for all users. e.g.

```
{ "4ffcfd9fe4b0211629c4ad06": { "read": true, "write": true }, "all" : { "read" : true } }
```

I can generate the first object using the technique you describe. I can generate the second entry (for all-users) but I can't figure out how to add the 2 entries to create the structure shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First -- you aren't using `JSON` -- you are using Javascript Object literal.

```
function create_acl(value) {
    var acl = {};
    acl[value] =  { "read": true, "write": true};
    return acl;
}
```

**Modified answer based on OPs comment:**

```
function create_acl(value) {
    var acl = {};
    acl[value] =  { "read": true, "write": true};
    acl["*"] =  { "read": true, "write": false};
    return acl;
}
```

As others have noted in their answers:

```
var test_acl = creat_acl("foobar");
console.log(test_acl["foobar"]["read"]);
console.log(test_acl.foobar.read);
// BUT NOT
//  console.log(test_acl.*.read);
// This is OK
console.log(test_acl["*"]["read"]);
console.log(test_acl["*"].read);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I had tried that and it works. The reason I moved away from that solution is because ultimately I have create an acl with 2 entries (objects) in it. e.g.{  "4ffcfd9fe4b0211629c4ad06": { "read": true, "write": true },
   "all" : {  "read" :  true } }. I can generate the first object using the technique you describe. I can generate the second entry (for all-users) but I can't figure out how to add the 2 entries to create the structure shown above. It's driving me nuts. I've spent nearly 2 days solving what should be a trivially simple action.

Comment: @user2693205 You should consider editing that into the question.

Comment: if you do `acl['all'] = {'read':true};` should not you get it? I cannot clearly understand what do you want...

Comment: I could have sworn you used `*` instead of `all.`  Either way, though, the answer still holds.

Comment: @A.S.Roma So obvious it was staring me in the face all along. I feel very dumb now and am laughing at myself. Oh dear. :-S  Thanks guys. I'm sure we've all been there. (Tom slinks off in shame...)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I did use * but for saome reason the comment input removed it. Many many thanks for your help. I was dumb and unhappy before, but at least I'm happy now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the square brackets notation to set the key/value pair.

```
acl = {};
acl[value] = {"read": true, "write": true};
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ry8kT/153/)**

```
var json_obj = {};
var value = 123;

json_obj[value] = {"read": true, "write": true}; 

alert(JSON.stringify(json_obj));
```

Result:

```
{ "123": {"read": true, "write": true}}
```

Also, if you need to access `read` and `write`:

```
json_obj[value]["read"]; // output - true
// or
json_obj[value]["write"]; // output - true
```